# setInterval() not working after clearInterval() in this Javascript code

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I have been ripping my hair off a couple of nights now with this problem:

I'm trying to create an expanding div with JavaScript. Here's the part of the HTML file:

```
<div id="bbc_div" class="bbc_div" style="display:none; height:200px;">
<input type="button" value="Show BBC" id="bbc_button" onclick="onclickBBC('bbc_div')" />
```

And here's the magical non-working JavaScript file:

```
var maxHeight = 100;
var curHeight = 1;
var wait = 5;
var timerID = new Array();

function onclickBBC(obj) {
    if (document.getElementById(obj).style.display == "none") {
        slideDown(obj);
    } 
    else {
        document.getElementById(obj).style.display="none"
    }
}

function slideDown(obj) {
    document.getElementById(obj).style.height="1px";
    document.getElementById(obj).style.display="block";
    timerID[obj] = setInterval("slideDownExec(\"" + obj + "\")", wait);
    return;
}

function slideDownExec(obj) {
    if (curHeight <= maxHeight) {
        curHeight++;
        document.getElementById(obj).style.height=curHeight + "px";
    }
    else {
        endSlide(obj);
    }
    return;
}

function endSlide(obj) {
    clearInterval(timerID[obj]);
    return;
}
```

When I reload the page, div expands once to its right height. But, if I push the button without reloading page again after it has hided again, it doesn't work. `display:block;` works, but `setInterval()` isn't starting. So this happens after `clearInterval()` has executed. Why is `clearInterval()` killing my `setInterval()` permanently?

Answer (score 1):

The timer is running, you just need to reset a variable:

```
    function slideDown(obj)
    {
        document.getElementById(obj).style.height = "1px";
        curHeight = 1;
```

I would use jQuery for this, it's a LOT easier.

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue with `curHeight` not being set to `1` at the top of `slideDown`. If this doesn't happen, the if statement at the top of `slideDownExec` will only work the first time.

Additionally, does JavaScript allow non-integer array indexes?

```
> a['i'] = 4
4
> a
[]
> a['i']
4
```

What you're actually doing is adding a property called `i` to the array object. You might as well use an empty object rather than an array.